# MeteorJS: Show/Hide leaving blank divs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am doing a show/hide by changing field type of `companyName` based on `customerType` answer

[image]
[image]

It works but instead of hiding the entire div, it seems to just make the opacity 0, leaving a blank spaces like so

[image]

When I inspect the elements it shows form group divs with no content

[image]

**UPDATE:** I am trying to keep the dependency logic on the schema. That way I can have 1 form html template and let the each form's schema handle it's show/hide logic. This approach will make it easy to maintain the forms. I am trying to avoid sing {{‪#‎if‬ variable}} {{/if}} per field.

**Is there a way to remove the blank divs if field is hidden?**

Answer (score 1):

You can update you type schema to "none" and on your view:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: {{type}}">
  Put your custype div/input fiel here
</div>
```

Disclaimer: not tested.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new helper:

```
isCompany: function(){
    return Autoform.getFieldValue("customerType") == "Company"; 
   // return true if custype is company
}
```

On your Customer div block:

```
{{#if isCompany}}
   Put your custype div/input fiel here
{{/if}}
```

--- with that, div block for company will onle be shown when custype is company .

Sorry if there are typos issues. I'm on mobile .

Comment: Hi Edion. I am trying to keep the dependency logic on the schema (2nd pic). That way I can have 1 form html template and let the each form handle it's show/hide logic. This approach will make it easy to maintain the forms.

Comment: Ah - it's a Css matters. Try display none. Not same with hidden it will totally make div disappear on users view.  Not leaving any space of div. hope it helps